# forms_with in view and proper routing to edit model attribute without redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, orm

I am following along the with the book 'Agile Web Develolpment with Rails 6' and have managed to build a simple e-commerce website. I have a catalog, a cart, products, and line items. I want to add some extra functionality to the cart view to improve usability. This functionality is not included in the book and I can't seem to find much about this specific use case on the internet.

The end-users are not consumers but retail stores interacting with our inventory. We deal with larger quantities in our orders, and each order is usually more complex. Therefore editing the quantity of a specific product through a simple increment/decrement button is not feasible. Instead I am attempting to add a small number-field form beside each line_item displayed in the cart so that users can easily make broad changes on multiple items with minimal interactions.

the problem is that i cannot find a good example for how to properly route the patch request to my line_item#edit_attribute method, nor am i currently able to organize the form in the view layer to connect with the router.

I'm not sure about the route of the cart, but when i click on add product from the catalog the url points to `line_items?product_id=[:id]`.

I am aware that i need to create a route that makes a url that points to my `line_items#edit_attribute` method and sends attribute name as well as the value (in this case quantity and an integer), but I have no idea how to do that.

relevant model:

`product has_many :line_items` 
`line_item belongs_to :product`
      `belongs_to :cart`
`cart has_many :line_items, dependent :destroy`

`line_item` schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema do
  create_table "line_items", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "product_id", null: false
    t.integer "cart_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null:false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null:false
    t.integer "quantity", default: 1
    t.integer "price"
    t.index ["cart_id"], name: "index_line_items_on_cart_id"
    t.index ["product_id"], name: "index_line_items_on_product_id"
  end

    add_foreign_key "line_items", "carts"
    add_foreign_key "line_items", "products"
  end
end
```

`LineItems` controller method:

```
def edit_attribute(attribute, value)
  @cart = Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
  @line_item = LineItem.find_by_id(params[:id])
  @line_item[attribute] = value
  #custom validations here
  @line_item.save
end
```

what i have for the view layer. note that it's incorrect and incomplete.:

```
<tr>
  <td class="quantity"> <%= line_item.quantity %> </td>
  <%= form_with  url: edit_attribute_line_item, method: :patch do |line_item| %>
    <%= form.number_field :quantity, in: 0..100, step: 1 %> 
  <% end %>
  <td><%= line_item.product.title %></td>
  <td class="price>"><%= number_to_currency(line_item) %> </td> 
</tr>
```

So how would i write the proper routing for this method and connect it to my view layer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to add a route, if you don't have one for this action:

```
  patch 'line_items/edit_attribute/:id', to: 'line_items#edit_attribute', as: :line_items_edit_attribute
```

You have `edit_attribute_line_item` in your form, but not sure if you have a route for that. The form url should be set the path: `line_items_edit_attribute`.

Comment: sounds easy enough! thanks. i'll give that a try.

Comment: this solution doesn't have a way to define the atribute being edited. as you can see in my controller and as the name of the method implies i must define the attribute as the first argument in the method. this is important to follow along with OOP best practices.

Comment: @Andrew - You're right. I have updated the answer and added the attribute id: `patch 'line_items/edit_attribute/:id'`.